# Seeking Advice for Upgrading Brake Control System with PWM

Tags: microcontroller, relay, pwm, solid-state-relay, fet

I'm working on improving our system's mechanical brake control mechanism. Currently, the brake is controlled by relays, but there are issues with oscillations (because it is a sudden and not smooth brake) and delayed stopping due to the mass of the arm when the brake is released (engaged and de-engaged). To address this, I've experimented with using PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) to gradually stop the brake, and it has shown promising results in reducing these problems.

I've connected one side of the relay to a microcontroller and the other side to an external relay that can transmit 24 V and handle up to 2 A. Many colleagues at my company have shown enthusiasm for this solution, and I'm now tasked with designing a board that will replace the existing relay card while retaining the PWM functionality.

My manager has suggested replacing the relays with FETs to eliminate mechanical noise. However, I have concerns about the FETs handling the 24 V and 1 A load without overheating.

I'm seeking advice on the best approach to achieve a 24 V, 1 A switch with PWM pulses. The PWM frequency does not exceed 1 kHz and is active only during the stopping phase. I'd appreciate insights on selecting appropriate FETs, relay, optocoupler relay, or something else from you, to hear about your advices.

Comment: What leads you to have concerns about mosfets overheating?  1A is a trivial amount of current for the average mosfet. Choose a device with adequate current and voltage rating and pay attention to the RdsOn parameter which is the effective on resistance. From that you can determine the temperature rise of the device. Go to Digikey and search for n channel mosfets and poke in your parameters to narrow the search. You could also research online popular devices and see how they fit your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My manager has suggested replacing the relays with FETs to eliminate mechanical noise.

This is generally a sound idea. Although even FETs can be regarded as having "bouncing properties" when toggling. While you don't have to "debounce" a MOSFET like you would have to do with a relay, you need to keep the switching time in mind while writing the software.

If for example the MOSFET isn't fast enough to keep up with the PWM frequency, then this will be a problem. The normal way to deal with that is to convert the PWM to an analog voltage first, through a diff op or maybe just a RC filter depending on your requirements and how much/little the analog signal is allowed to oscillate. There should be plenty of solutions for this elsewhere on this site.

In general you might want to look into "fast switching high-side drivers" which is essentially a N-MOSFET, an internal regulator and protection electrionics. A whole lot of these are designed for 24VDC specifically.

Switching time, Rds(on) and Vgs versus MCU signal levels would be the important parameters (and current rating, obviously). Just pick something reasonably modern/highly recommended by the manufacturer.

> However, I have concerns about the FETs handling the 24 volts and 1 amp load without overheating.

1A is not really any concern and the MOSFET can likely handle that just fine without much in the way of a heatsink. Ideally provide a bit of PCB heatsink as a copper plane on the top layer. Many driver IC have a heatsink pad underneath.

> I'm seeking advice on the best approach to achieve a 24 volt, 1 amp switch with PWM pulses.

This depends on how advanced it needs to be. Likely a "soft ramping" PWM will already be a nice improvement. A more advanced system would involve reading back the actual status of the device and form a control loop.

There is no reason to use optocouplers. Just ensure that you have sufficient protection. In terms of driving some coil or motor with the MOSFET, that means a freewheel diode across the load. And industrial electronics in general will have TVS on all 24V supply and I/O.